# How do I export a subset of slides of a MS Power Point presentation as a video?

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, export

I have a long power point presentation and I would like to export it into several videos, to keep the length of each video down, and also to reduce the export time of each individual video.
When exporting a presentation into a PDF, one can specify a subset of slides to be exported. However, I don't find such an option for videos (MP4 in my case).

Is there a way of specifying a subset of slides so that only those get exported as a video?

I do not want to cut the video with an external tool, if that tool requires importing and then re-exporting. And splitting the presentation up into parts is not desirable, even though that would be my last resort.

Comment: Have you tried hiding the slides you don't want included in the exported video? Haven't tested this myself, but if hiding the slides doesn't exclude them from the video, I'd consider it a bug.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. I thought that would screw up the page number (or rather slide number), but somehow, it counts hidden slides, which I didn't expect. But that did solve my problem. I just forgot to write that as an answer here.

Comment: Usually the request is for PPT to ignore hidden slides when numbering slides; glad that this worked in your favor.